# How can I get PHP working through my websites hosted on GCP to allow browser based file uploads to my hosting space?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

It seems like ALL scripts I attempt to build and run through my website on GCP are failing to load, and I have searched off and on now for months trying to see if building in PHP is plausible through this setup. 
It would be of great help to get the price of GCP working with my 501(c) webdesign needs.

Running scripts through the site.

Researching articles and programs related are seemingly inadequate for use with GCP Buckets or the web-hosting.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
```

I expected to be able to run PHP while hosting my website through GCP.

When I upload my php scripts and visit them live on my browser, they are not running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHP to use different GCP products as App Engine, Cloud SQL, Cloud Storage or Cloud Datastore, you can follow the [PHP Bookshelf App](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/tutorial-app).

Furthermore, in case you want to use App Engine with your PHP code, here is the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/). You can follow the quickstarts for either Standard or Flexible environment in order to know how to proceed.

Comment: Okay so I'll have to study up on App Engine, PHP and HTML integration if I want to work with these code sets and GCP for my project.

Comment: I would follow the step by step explanations in order to know how it works, and then apply the changes based on your code. Hope that the links were useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to execute PHP code in GCP.
I think the problem is not from your PHP code but GCP.

You can go to https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/tutorial-app to learn how to use PHP inside GCP.